# ¿Como recuperar valores desde un fichero JSON para tratarlas con un sript python?

Tags: python, json

Tengo un fichero JSON `valorMercado.js` con las valores siguientes :

```
{"BTC":{"USD":2167.85},"ETH":{"USD":167.88},"DASH":{"USD":102.31}}
{"BTC":{"USD":2253.12},"ETH":{"USD":177.76},"DASH":{"USD":109.17}}
{"BTC":{"USD":2251.47},"ETH":{"USD":177.71},"DASH":{"USD":109.12}}
...
```

Cada vez se añade una nueva linea, quiero hacer la media sobre los cincos ultimos números de cada moneda para hacer la media móvil simple ("Simple Moving Average"). Sin embargo, no se como recuperar las valores desde el fichero valorMercado.js para tratarlas.

```
import numpy as np

# leer el fichero, cada vez hay una otra valor poner las 5 ultimas en a y la ultima en lastValue

fiveLast = np.array(a[-5:])
lastValue = a[-1]

# calculemos sma
fiveLastMean = np.mean(fiveLast)

# poner en marcha una alerta si lastValue < o > nowValue

for i in a.shape[1] :
    if (fiveLastMean[1] < nowValue[1]):
        result[i] = buy
    else if(fiveLastMean[1] > nowValue[1]):
        result[i] = sell
```

El output debería ser una matriz de variables que pertenecen a {buy, leave, sold}. Por ejemplo :

```
[buy, buy, leave]
```

Por "compra BTC, ETH y no hace nada con DASH".

Comment: ¿qué son los moneros? Iría bien que completaras el [mcve].

Comment: @fedorqui, "monedas", me disculpe. Pensaba añadir en el codigo `a = [[2000.20,234.32,289.25],[2105.58,254.25,259.32],[1999.12,238.36,189.47],[2001.11,235.00,279.58],[2010.23,250.98,299.20],[2100.25,204.69,200.65]]` y decir que viene del fichero JSON y que esta necesario resplacarlo pero lo que busco esta como resplacar lo y pensaba esta cambiaría la pregunta.

Comment: Bueno lo importante también es indicar cuál es la salida que esperas que proporcione tu script a partir del ejemplo que indicas. De este modo será más fácil comprobar que nos estamos entendiendo :)

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, tal como escribiste el ejemplo de un fichero el mismo no parece ser un JSON válido, supongo que debiera tener los `[]` para indicar que se trata de una lista y un `,`para separar cada ítem. Si efectivamente lo tienes tal como lo indicas, debiéramos en primer lugar re-formatearlo tal como lo menciono para poder leerlo como Json.

Usando `json.loads`para leer desde un cadena de caracteres o bien `json.load`para leer directamente del archivo, resulta todo bastante sencillo.

```
import json
import numpy as np

json_text = """
[
{"BTC":{"USD":2167.85},"ETH":{"USD":167.88},"DASH":{"USD":102.31}},
{"BTC":{"USD":2253.12},"ETH":{"USD":177.76},"DASH":{"USD":109.17}},
{"BTC":{"USD":2251.47},"ETH":{"USD":177.71},"DASH":{"USD":109.12}}
]
"""

a = json.loads(json_text)

values = [(each["BTC"].get("USD"), each["ETH"].get("USD"), each["DASH"].get("USD")) for each in a]

fiveLast = np.array(values[-5:])

print(fiveLast)
```

Luego de leer el Json válido lo que obtenemos es una lista de diccionarios en la jerga de Python, lo que hacemos luego es convertir dicha lista en una lista de tuplas dónde básicamente cada columna es el valor de BTC.USD, ETH.USD, DASH.USD. Convertir esto a un array numpy es trivial.

```
[[ 2167.85   167.88   102.31]
 [ 2253.12   177.76   109.17]
 [ 2251.47   177.71   109.12]]
```